# Visual studio 20 19 - Mac - workloads during installation

Tags: mac, visual-studio-2019, extension

for developing our applications, our developers require the Azure development workload to be installed with their Visual Studio 2019. This works fine in Windows, it's just a optional workload/extension during the installer process.

However this option doesn't seem to be available during the installation on mac devices. The list of workloads is extremely limited for mac (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/installation?view=vsmac-2019).

Documentation on installation for mac, seems to be rather limited. Is there a method we could follow add the necessary workload for mac?

> I've verified with our developers. The reason we need the workload is mainly because we make use of [DefaultAzureCredential](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) to use the user's profile from Visual Studio to connect to Azure Key Vault. In windows this account is available under *Tools > Options > Azure services authentication * which is only available after installing the Azure development workload.

[image: vs installer]